# Is there an easier way to shift an array to the left in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I was doing a simple problem in python of shifting an array to the left using python 3.0
for the problem I have I only need to have a length of 3 for the array. For example if my array is `[1, 2, 3]`
after the shift it should read `[2,3,1]`. My code works but I was wondering if anyone could guide me to making it more efficient, as well as doing it for any array length if possible.
My issue is that I don't think I know how to shift all the elements at once, instead I shift all the elements after the first element, and then I append the first element to the array after the loop.

```
def rotate_left3(nums):
    shifted_nums=[]
    i=len(nums)
    for j in range(i):
        shifted_nums=nums[j-1:]
    var=nums[0]
    shifted_nums.append(var)
    return shifted_nums
```

Comment: Hi if you are referring to switch that with the assignment in the for loop, I tried it and it gave the same array as the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? simply copy the array without the first element first.

```
def rotate_left3(nums):
  shifted_nums = nums[1:]
  shifted_nums.append(nums[0])
  return shifted_nums
```

Comment: This works! Didn't think of it, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to do is by using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque). It supports fast appends and pops on either end and has a method called [`rotate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) to achieve what you want:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> de = deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> de
deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> de.rotate(2)
>>> de
deque([3, 4, 1, 2])
>>> de.rotate(-2)
>>> de
deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: This method works! Thank you, I hope to use more of it in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this

```
shifted_left_arr = arr[1:] + [arr[0]]
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, can you please explain why there is [] around arr[0]?

Comment: its to append 2 list together, its part of python list comprehension.